# What am I clicking on bootstrap modal back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When i open modal and open console I get in my body `class='modal-open'` 
and I get

`<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>`
I need to get what am I clicking on what is background behind the modal.

```
$(".modal-backdrop").click(function(){

    $('input[name="report"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="block"]').prop('checked', false);    

});

$(".close").click(function(){

    $('input[name="report"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="block"]').prop('checked', false);    

});
```

`class="close"` is X on modal
But also when I click on back on the black transparent background
it closes modal but clicked inputs stay same. I want to reset them like with X button.
I tried `.modal-backdrop and .modal-open` but I can't see which one is connected to that back area.
Anyone know the answer?

SLOVED

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;


    $('.modal-dialog').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside)

    $('input[name="report"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="block"]').prop('checked', false);    


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do that when the modal is closed, with this event

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('input[name="report"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="block"]').prop('checked', false); 
})
```